# Como alinhar strings para utilizar em um listview?

Tags: java, android, string, array, listview

Em meu projeto Android eu preciso criar uma tabela com um `listview` mas os dados sempre vem desalinhados. Eu coloco cada registro do meu banco de dados em uma posição de um array de strings para assim usá-lo no `listview`. O método que uso para tentar alinhar é esse:

```
public static String CompletaEspacos(String palavra) {
    if (palavra == null) {
        palavra = "";
    }
    String retorno = "";

    palavra = palavra.trim();

    if(palavra.length()>=19){
        retorno = palavra.substring(0,19);
    } else {
        retorno = String.format("%-19s", palavra);
    }       
    return retorno;
}
```

Ou seja cada "célula" da tabela contem uma palavra até seu 19º caractere ou uma palavra menor com espaços até chegar em 19. Essa é minha lógica porém não está funcionando. Qual a melhor maneira de criar as strings de um array para montar uma tabela alinhada em um `listview` em Java.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer dizer com "não está funcionando"?

Comment: Não conheço bem a programação em Android, mas faz diferença isso estar nele ou em qualquer dispositivo Java?

Comment: Não seria melhor utilizar os próprios parâmetros de alinhamento de ListView? Com o android:textAlignment="center".

Comment: bfavaretto, eu gostaria que os dados ficassem alinhados para formar uma tabela, porém eles não ficam alinhados com o titulo

Comment: @anovaesneto, sendo assim, acho que é melhor fazer uma TableLayout se comportar como uma ListView, isso pode ser visto [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873556/focusable-row-inside-table-android/5258310#5258310)

Comment: @felipe.avelar, pelo que eu entendi do seu exemplo ele usou um número determinado de linhas na tabela. porém eu busco os dados da minha listview no banco, não sei quantas linhas serão.

Comment: @anovaesneto podia mandar uma imagem para demonstrar como sua lista está ficando.

Comment: @anovaesneto uma imagem seria bom, mas me parece que você está usando a fonte padrão que tem larguras diferentes para cada caracter. Você precisa configurar este ListView para usar `Droid Sans Mono` (`monospace`)

Comment: Este é o tipo de solução que preferia deixar no banco ao invés da view tratar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para isto você precisa usar fontes monoespaçadas, como por exemplo Courier (ou a nativa *Droid Sans Mono*, como apontado pelo @Alexandre Marcondes).

Fontes monoespaçadas, diferentemente das fontes proporcionais, são aquelas em que todas as letras tem as mesmas larguras. Veja só a comparação:

**Exemplo 1**

XMILSW
WWMWMW
i01 .m

**Exemplo 2**

```
XMILSW
WWMWMW
i01 .m
```

Perceba que no primeiro caso as letras não se alinham e no segundo sim.

Dê uma olhadinha na documentação do [typeface MONOSPACE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#MONOSPACE) para ver algumas opções nesse sentido.

> Considere o [Grid View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) como alternativa. O Grid View permite ter várias colunas separadas, alinhadas independentemente do conteúdo.

Comment: Como a pergunta que foi feita depois está sendo marcada como duplicada (com razão), passei a resposta pra cá. (duplicata em http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/2509/problema-com-alinhamento-de-string )

Comment: Eu não tinha pensado no monospace, caso a `ListView` tenha só uma coluna, acho que está é a melhor solução.

Comment: Pessoal consegui fazer o que eu queria colocando o GridView e usando um adaptador que herdasse de BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 8):

Baseado nos comentários, pude entender que o que você quer é uma ListView dinâmica. Para isso, você precisará criar uma `Adapter` especificamente para isso e preencher cada linha da `ListView` com um xml específico, próprio para alinhar.

Para ajudar, encontrei esse [tutorial](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/dynamic-listview-in-android/) que o próprio autor escreve ser uma boa solução quando vai se preencher uma `ListView` com dados de uma base de dados.

Eu editei o código dele para ficar um pouco mais genérico, vou dividir em partes:

## Classe da lista

```
package com.dynalist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyList extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListView listView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_country);
        listView.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    }
    private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return CountriesList.abbreviations.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.two_col_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.text1.setText(CountriesList.abbreviations[position]);
            holder.text2.setText(CountriesList.countries[position]);

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView text1;
            TextView text2;
        }
    }
}
```

Distrinchando essa classe temos:

```
private ListView listView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_country);
    listView.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
}
```

Nesse trecho ele cria a lista a partir de um layout pré-definido e salva a referência na variável `ListView` para usar posteriormente, junto a isso ele atribui um `Adapter` para essa lista, o qual é definido internamente da classe nesse exemplo(por questões de organização de código isso não é a forma mais correta de fazer, o que correto seria encapsular a classe e importá-la). O `Adapter` fica responsável pelo conteúdo da lista, quando você atribui um `Adapter`, você está atribuindo o "background de dados". Retirado da própria documentação da [ListView do Google Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29), tratando do parâmetro `adapter` do tipo `ListAdapter`:

> The ListAdapter which is responsible for maintaining the data backing this list and for producing a view to represent an item in that data set.

Em tradução livre:

> O ListAdapter o qual será responsável por manter os dados dessa lista e por produzir uma view para representar um item que está no conjunto de dados.

Dentro da classe `EfficientAdapter` ele cria alguns métodos auxiliares, mas o principal método é o `getView`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.two_col_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } 
    holder.text1.setText(CountriesList.abbreviations[position]);
    holder.text2.setText(CountriesList.countries[position]); 
    return convertView;
}
```

Com esse método ele inicializa **UMA LINHA** da `ListView`, como tratado anteriormente. Cada linha é uma view com dois `TextView` do layout `two_col_rol`, que será apresentado a seguir.

### Mas como ele popula a lista?

O "macete" fica nos métodos `getCount`, `getItem` e `getItemId`, que faz ele iterar por todas as entradas dele (no caso uma lista de abreviações de países), permitindo que, a partir de um vetor, ele popule toda a lista com o `getView`.

## XML da lista

No exemplo ele coloca um cabeçalho e uma "linha de legendas", eu preferi tratar só o `XML`da `ListView` para a resposta não ficar mais extensa ainda.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffccd0"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_country"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Tudo o que ele faz é uma `ListView` normal que não precisa de muita atenção, já que é uma lista básica, não há muito o que comentar.

## A view de cada linha da Lista

Aqui é onde fica o outro "segredo" de fazer uma lista dinâmica alinhada. Como cada linha é uma `View`, basta você alinhar o texto a partir do `android:gravity` como é mostrado no `XML` abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingLeft="3px">
     <!-- Coluna 1 -->
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#d08021"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"/>
     <!--Coluna 2-->
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#7f0000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Como, no seu caso, só é necessário uma coluna, é basta deixar um `TextView`, com a formatação que você desejar.

Comment: irei testar então o código desse tutorial e qualquer coisa lhe aviso

Comment: @felipe-avelar, bem vindo ao SOPT, por favor, poste o código do tutorial que mandou, de como usar um Adapter, e mantenha o link como referênca, link podem ficar obsoletos, as respostas não deve cair juntamente com o link

Comment: @hernandes, acho que agora ficou um pouco melhor a resposta. (:

Comment: show de bola!!!